# Installing backuppc on Ubuntu 20.04 and ran into a problem downloading and compiling?

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, compiling

Ok, following the directions here : https://kifarunix.com/install-and-setup-backuppc-server-on-ubuntu-20-04/

I get all the way down to the "Install backuppc on Ubuntu 20.04"

while in the directory backuppc...

## Generate the latest release BackupPC tarball from the source file and BackupPC build tools;

VER=`curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/backuppc/backuppc/releases/latest" | grep '"tag_name":' | sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'`

## Then I try this

./makeDist --nosyntaxCheck --releasedate "date -u "+%d %b %Y"" --version $VER

## Error I get below :

Option version requires an argument

usage: ./makeDist [--nolangCheck] [--nosyntaxCheck] [--releasedate 'DD MMM YYYY'] --version X.Y.Z

It acts like it wants a date ?  But I can't get anything to work with it?

It should create BackupPC tarball and store is under dist directory in the current working directory as, dist/BackupPC-4.3.2.tar.gz.

Never happens.  What in that last code looks wrong, or what am I missing ?

Many thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Your ./makeDist command is failing due to a --releasedate date formatting problem.

You have:

```
./makeDist --nosyntaxCheck --releasedate "date -u "+%d %b %Y"" --version $VER
```

So use this:

```
./makeDist --nosyntaxCheck --releasedate $(date -u '+%d %b %Y') --version $VER
```

Or this:

```
./makeDist --nosyntaxCheck --releasedate '30 Jun 2020' --version $VER
```

Comment: Ahhhh, you are a genius !  That did the trick !

Comment: 2nd one got it for me ; ./makeDist --nosyntaxCheck --releasedate '30 Jun 2020' --version 4.3.2

Comment: @EricP Great! Please remember to accept my answer. Thanks!